# Is an .RDP file cross-platform?

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop

If you create an .RDP file on a windows machine by using the save as feature, can you then use the same .RDP file on a mac if the mac has a proper RDP client installed, such as "RD Client"?

If not, what are the things I need to look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you mean a "proper RDP client" such as the [Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=18140), it will open .rdp files. I just checked with a .rdp file on my machine, copied it to a nearby Mac with the RDCCfM installed, and tried it on that too. As a bonus, I also tried it on the Remote Desktop Connection Client for Android, and that worked, too.